# I need help updating my "total" for it to display onto the Window (Python)

Tags: python, user-interface

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg

menu_dictionary = {
    "Burger": 3.5,
    "Onions": 0.75,
    "Bacon": 1.25,
    "Eggs": 1.00,
    "Gatorade": 1.25
}
total=0
sg.theme('DarkAmber')

layout = [
        [sg.Text("Welcome to the MAF Menu")],
        [sg.Text("Entrees"), sg.Button("Burger"), sg.Button("Sandwhich"), sg.Button("Hot Dog"), sg.Button("Eggs")],
        [sg.Text("Sides"),sg.Button("Onions"), sg.Button("Pickles"), sg.Button("Cheese")],
        [sg.Text("Total $" + str(total))] ,
        [sg.Button("Exit")],]

window = sg.Window('MAF Menu', layout)

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event == 'Exit':
        exit()
    if event == "Burger":
        total = total + menu_dictionary["Burger"]
        print(total)
    if event == "Onions":
        total = total + menu_dictionary["Onions"]
        print(total)


print(total)
window.close()
```

I need help displaying the actual total onto the UI window. I have tried multiple different avenues and research but I cannot find anything about updates. I am using simplepyGUI in pycharm. I am very new to python and need a little bit of help.

Answer (score 0):

Add key to the element to find the element when update.

```py
        [sg.Text("Total $" + str(total), key='Total')],
```

Call method `update` to update the element.

```py
    if event in menu_dictionary:
        total = total + menu_dictionary[event]
        window['Total'].update("Total $" + str(total))
```